# Popular tabela no angular 8

Tags: json, angular, typescript, front-end, angular-8

Bom dia,

Estou tentando popular uma tabela no meu sistema, pois o backend feito em spring me manda um JSON da seguinte maneira, um objeto com várias listas dentro, exemplo:

```
{
"contasDespesasQuitadas": [
],
"contasDespesasAbertas": [
],
"contasReceitasQuitadas": [
],
"contasReceitasAbertas": [
]}
```

No TS, eu tento popular a table da seguinte maneira:

```
filtrarDatas() {
if (this.dataInicial && this.dataFinal) {
  this.resultadoService.resultByPeriodFinal(this.dataInicial,this.dataFinal)
      .subscribe(res => {
       this.popularTabelaReceitaAberta(res.contasReceitasAbertas);
       this.totalReceitaAberta();

       this.popularTabelaReceitaQuitada(res.contasReceitasQuitadas);
       this.totalReceitaQuitada();

       this.popularTabelaDespesaAberta(res.contasDespesasAbertas);
       this.totalDespesaAberta();

       this.popularTabelaDespesaQuitada(res.contasDespesasQuitadas);
       this.totalDespesaQuitada();
  });
}
```

No sistema a tabela é populada corretamente, porém a IDE apresenta uma mensagem de erro:

Property 'contasReceitasAbertas' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Isso acontece em todas as tabelas, o erro aparece depois que eu coloco "res.contasReceitasAbertas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é comum no Angular, devido a tipagem de dados do **Typescript**, como no seu código por exemplo, quando vc faz a seguinte declaração:

```
(res.contasReceitasAbertas)
```

Vc declarou **`res`** mas o Typescript não sabe se pode atribuir **contasReceitasAbertas** a res, exatamente pela tipagem. Para contornar isto basta tipar a variável res com o tipo **any** por exemplo:

```
.subscribe((res: any) => {
```

Que o erro não deverá acontecer mais. Se puder dá uma lida [neste](https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/typescript-entendendo-a-nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-tipos-9e8c1c89ef62) artigo que explica muita coisa lá.

Comment: Deu certo usando o ".subscribe((res: any) => {"

Comment: Legal man, sucesso aí!

Comment: valeu, sucesso também.